# Keep leading zeros when saving numbers that start with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to save a list of site codes, for example:

```
site_codes = [1302,9033,1103,5005,0016]
```

Then I want to add the site code to URLs before running web scraping, using `site_codes[i]`, for example:

```
for i in range(len(site_codes)): 
  
  Data_site_A.append("https://.../"+str(parameters[i])+"site="+str(site_codes[0]))
  Data_site_B.append("https://.../"+str(parameters[i])+"site="+str(site_codes[1]))
```

But I can not save `0016` into the list just like other numbers. I have tried many ways including:

```
# make a string
str("{0}{1}{2}".format(0,0,16))

# fill the 0
"%04d" % 16
```

But they all return `'0016'` instead of `0016`. So when I input `'0016'` into the urls, it won't work, because it is not a number.

Is there a way to save this number just as `0016`? Or since that `print("%04d" % 16)` will print out a pure `0016`, is there a way to save the output from there?

For the desired output, the computer should interpret it as:

```
"https://...."+str(parameters[i])+"site=0016")
```

Comment: Why not do this: `site_codes = ['1302','9033','1103','5005','0016']` , store the things as string, because "0016" is clearly a string, and 0016 is not a string, but 16 is a number.

Comment: You're already casting all values of `site_codes` into strings in your code, so why not just store them that way in the beginning? Nothing in your provided code should break if they are all strings.

Comment: Because the site codes are not decided by me, I am using the links to download data from a platform, and the codes anre target urls are just like that.

Comment: But the URL **is** **a** **string** after you've concatenated all your variables to it. As I said, nowhere in your posted code is there a reason for them to be anything other than a string.

Comment: `site_codes = [1302,9033,1103,5005,16]; str("{0:04}").format(site_codes[4])`  will output `'0016'`  (but i am not a python programmer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# use regular expression

import re

site_codes = '''
         site code:
         site_A: 1302
         site_B: 9033
         site_C: 1103
         site_D: 5005
         site_E: 0016
         '''

site_codes = re.findall(r'\d+',site_codes)

for i in range(len(site_codes)): 
    Data_site_A.append("https://.../"+str(parameters[i])+"site="+str(site_codes[0]))
    Data_site_B.append("https://.../"+str(parameters[i])+"site="+str(site_codes[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.zfill()` to add leading zeros to a number;
Call `str(object)` with a number as object to convert it to a string.
Call `str.zfill(width)` on the numeric string to pad it with 0 to the specified width.

```
print(a_number)

OUTPUT=
123
```

Convert `a_number` to a string

```
number_str = str(a_number)
```

Pad `number_str` with zeros to 5 digits

```
zero_filled_number = number_str.zfill(5)

print(zero_filled_number)

OUTPUT=
00123
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really do have a list of integers that can't be retained as strings and want to create the URLs. Also assuming that you are using Python 3.6 or above, you can achieve this with a simple [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
print(f"https://.../{str(parameters[i])}site={site_codes[1]:04d}")
```

This will pad with leading zeros without the need to resort to zfill.

Alternatively, or if you're running Python below 3.6, this will also work:

```
print("https://.../{}site={:04d}".format(str(parameters[i]), site_codes[1]))
```

With a site code of 16, both of the above will give you

https://.../parametersite=0016